# Using React Hooks to pass props down from a parent to a child function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to using hooks (and React in general) and I am having trouble figuring out how to pass in props from a parent function to a child function. useSquare is a custom hook and I want to pass square1_state and setSquare_state into it. I then want to pass setSquare_state to the handle_square_click function. I was following the example on this https://designcode.io/react-hooks-handbook-props but for me the square_state and setSquare_state are not recognized. Appreciate any help.

```
   const handle_square_click = (setSquare_state) => {
    setSquare_state(player)
    setGetplayer(true)
  }

  const useSquare = (square_state, setSquare_state) => {
    // Hook for square state management and rendering
    return (
        <button className="square" onClick={<handle_square_click setSquare_state={setSquare_state}/> }>
          {square_state}
        </button>
    );
  }

  const Board = ({player}) => {
    let status = "Next Player : " + player
    const [square1_state, setSquare1_state] = useState(1);
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="status">{status}</div>
        <div className="board-row">
          <useSquare
            square_state={square1_state}
            setSquare_state={setSquare1_state}
          />
```

Comment: Hello! Just for start, your useSquare custom hook is not a custom hook as it's not using any of the react lifecycle APIs like useState or useEffect etc, there's no state being handled in this function. Second, you're using useSquare as a pure react component, so the guidelines recommend that you just name it like const Square etc. Third, the useSquare (which is in fact a component) doesn't receive multiple parameters as you have there, it receives some props which can be deconstructed as you did in Board

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I can provide some code so you can execute it, however there will be no custom hook as there's no state management happening except in the Board

```
   const handle_square_click = (setSquare_state) => {
    setSquare_state(player)
    setGetplayer(true)
  }

  const SquareSubmit = ({square, setSquare}) => {
    // Hook for square state management and rendering
    // As mentioned, this is not a custom hook at all
    return (
        <button className="square" onClick={() => handle_square_click(setSquare)}>
          {square}
        </button>
    );
  }

  const Board = ({player}) => {
    let status = "Next Player : " + player
    // I removed _state as it doesn't provide any useful information
    const [square1, setSquare1] = useState(1);
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="status">{status}</div>
        <div className="board-row">
          <SquareSubmit
            square={square1}
            setSquare={setSquare1}
          />
```